# How to add an HTML comment to the head of every page?

Tags: 7

I'm looking to add a copyright message to every page of my website using Drupal 7. The easiest way to do this would be to add it into the header, since that appears everywhere. I know that changes can be made to html.tpl.php.

But I'm unfamiliar (for now) with php, and need to know if I need to add any special commands to the php or can I just inject my comment into the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using a more Drupal-centric solution. If you're looking to place some static copyright info, you can create a block of HTML and place it in a footer region of your site's theme (under the block administration area).

If you're just looking to play around with the Drupal CMS & PHP coding in general (off topic for Drupal Answers), as long as you make your changes outside of the `<?php ?>` tags you should be fine to make changes to your template file.

Comment: The less PHP I have to deal with the better fo sho. I'll add it into the footer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So over a year later, there's two paths to do this:

If the (c) needs to appear publicly create a block with the copyright information and then add the block to a region on your page. In my case it was added to the footer.

If you're looking to add it to the source code (and therefore not publicly listed) add it to html.tpl.php down toward the bottom but above the `</body>` tag. Using a standard HTML comment (i.e., `<!--- Copyright (c) 2017, Ad Nauseam corp. --->` ) no php commands needed. (Note: this probably isn't the most Drupalific way of doing this.)